# Load a new page based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code where I have some links:

```
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
  <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
  <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
  <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
  <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
  <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
};
```

I want the links to open on the same page, but they currently open in a new window. How can I get them to open on the same page?

Comment: Whats that `[1]` in `<option value="http://www.espn.com"[1]>ESPN</option>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: I made some changes to your post, trying to make the problem statement clearer. It's good to give information to help people answer, but try to make sure it's relevant and necessary for the question. Also you say open on the same page, do you mean the current tab or a new tab in the current window? What *exactly* you want isn't entirely clear, but the link above probably helps.

Comment: @CodeiSir That seems to have been accidentally formatting when posting. They set up a link to ESPN, presumably misunderstanding the link options.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` always opens a new window (or a new tab, depending on your browser).

Instead, set the `location` of the current window:

```
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  window.location.href = this.options.value;
};
```

*(note that you no longer need to find the value via `options[selectedIndex]` - the `value` of the `<select>` element itself will do)*

```js
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1');

urlmenu.onchange = function() {
  document.location.href = this.value;
};
```

```html
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
  <option>Choose:</option>
  <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
  <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
  <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
  <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
  <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location = "http://www.example.com"` to go to another link ([info](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1');
urlmenu.onchange = function () {
    window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
};
</script>
```

DEMO:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="menu1" id="menu1">
    <option value="http://www.espn.com" [1]>ESPN</option>
    <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
    <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
    <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
    <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu1');
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to w3: `window.open()` - open a new window;
`window.location.assign()` method loads a new document.

So use `window.location.assign()`. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_assign)